# Getting method descriptions to show in Apex intellisense

Tags: apex, vs-code

I am just getting started on Apex development using VS Code, Salesforce CLI, and the official Salesforce VS Code extensions, and while I have gotten intellisense working, I am not seeing any of the descriptions for methods etc.  All I get for available methods are names and signatures.

Is it possible to get the documentation / descriptions for methods to show in intellisense as well?  This is pictured in the Salesforce doc for using VS Code (see the gif demo at the top of [Write Apex Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/writing)), but I have searched several times over the last week or two for others with a similar issue or for any documentation or how-to's on getting this to work, and all I can find are instructions for getting intellsense working *at all*, which is not an issue for me.

I am familiar with, and have been using, the [Apex Language Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ref_guide.htm), but hopping over to a browser every few minutes to check the doc on a method is a lot more disruptive than having it available inline in the IDE.

Comment: If the methods or properties of file has JSDoc comments, they shows up in the intellisense dialog as description.

Comment: @Raul Thanks, I did play around with that and see that it worked for my own code, but I was hoping to be able to get this for the Salesforce-provided Apex classes etc.  Perhaps I need to find and add the source code for them to my local project?  (Assuming that's even available someplace.)

Comment: Ouch, I am afraid in that case, salesforce hasn't added description in their classes :-/